# For LOOP in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Total EmpId in Database = 74. 
Active Days for September 2013 in Databse = 22
I want to segregate the dates when the employee was not filled the production in MIS_Opus table.

Since FULL OUTER Join was not worked, I m using the except query. Through this query, I can get the unfilled dates for each employee by passing the empid thru c# function. For that loop will going to SQL & back to C# for 74 times. Please let me know how can I get the unfilled dates for all employees at one shot in SQL itself. I m using SQL 2012 and VS 2012 c#.

Thank you,

```
select _Date from MIS_BM_Calendar c
where c.Month = 'September 2013'  and c.DayShiftStatus = 'active'
except
select _Date from MIS_Opus o
where o.EmpId=@Empid
```

Comment: We don't write for loops in SQL - and we try to avoid writing loops at all. SQL is (generally) a declarative, set-based language - you tell the system what the entire result set should look like, and it works out whether to build up that result set using loops, hash tables, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to build a list of all employee + day combinations using a `cross join`.  Then you can use a `left join` to check if there is an employee entry for that day.

```
select  days._Date as TheDay
,       emps.EmpId as EmployeeWithMissingEntry
from    (
        select  distinct _Date
        from    MIS_BM_Calendar
        where   Month = 'September 2013'
                and DayShiftStatus = 'active'
        ) days
cross join -- One row for each combination of employee and date
        (
        select  distinct EmpId
        from    MIS_Opus
        ) emps
left join
        MIS_Opus o
on      o._Date = days._Date
        and o.EmpId = emps.EmpId
where   o._Date is null -- Employee entry for day not found
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andomar. This query shows me a very different attitude how to think programmatically.